# Firebase conversion for dynamic link event misses campaign attribution

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-console

**I use the firebase services** in my application and firebase google analytics. **I have several dynamic deep links**, which are build programmatically inside my application. *(The links are also used for
notifications or newsletters, as they work all the way)*

When a user opens a dynamic link that he/she received by another user,
one of the `dynamic_link_*` events is triggered and send to analytics.

**I added utm parameters to the links**, using the `DynamicLink.GoogleAnalyticsParameters.Builder` and marked the `dynamic_link_*` events as conversion. My utm parameters are custom ones, I do not have a network for them.

**i.e.:** Source: *my_application*, medium: *share*, campaign: *xyActivity*

**Unfortunately, neither the campaign, nor the source or medium is set in the conversion event details.**

Although, I see that the utm parameters are(!) attached to the event, in the **StreamView.**

The documentation says, this will autmatically be collected. But it won't *or* I am doing something very wrong.

I thought that it is maybe related to the fact, that my utm parameters are not related to any network. But I can't find any option to add a custom one in the Network Settings tab of the conversion details.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Please see comments below! It took almost 1 1/2 Month
to have results in the conversion overview!**

[image]

Comment: Have you found the answer? I might be facing similar issue.

Comment: @Slavo unfortunately not

Comment: After a lot of time, it seems that firebase (like always with events) needs some time to collect enough of them (anonymization) to show results. All the parameters now appear in the conversion view.

Comment: I would like to keep this question open as I still would like to know, until which threshold firebase will show no content.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re - Hey, having a complete existential breakdown at work about this exact problem. Did you make any headway/come to some concrete conclusions on this?

Comment: @ThomasCook Unfortunately I can't tell you anything new, besides that you need to wait some amount of time and my second guess is, that the data will only be displayed, once a relevant number of different sources (users) will push this event. For privacy reasons. But I don't have any prove for this.